# Let $f(x)=\arctan (\sin x+\cos x)$ be defined on $[0,2\pi]$. Then prove that the function is increasing in $x\in [0,\pi/4)\cup(5\pi/4,2\pi]$

Tags: functions, inequality

$$f’(x)=\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{1+(\sin x+\cos x)^2}$$

The denominator doesn’t really matter in this case, so I will ignore it
$$=\sqrt 2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4} -x\right)$$

For the function to be increasing

$$0<\frac{\pi}{4}-x<\pi$$
$$-\frac{3\pi}{4}<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Working in the given domain $$x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{4})$$

I am not able to prove for the second part. How should I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want $-3\pi/4 + 2k\pi < x < \pi/4+2k\pi$ for $k$ integer. In $[0, 2\pi]$ you can also take $k=1$, not only $k = 0$.